# How can I get useful/personal files in android?

Tags: android, database, file, search

I'm using Android. I'm inspired that Adobe Reader can list all my personal .pdf files and QQ music can find all my music files automatically. And they're not like confused by other .mp3 or .pdf files in my SDcard(There may be many .mp3 files like bell rings). How can I do the same thing? I mean to get user's personal files by searching or some other ways but get rid of those annoying system/software files.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd like to know what filters do you actually want? Media files? Only Audio files? Only documents? That will help us answer in a better

Make use of `FileNameFilter` interface. Link for reference: [FileNameFilter Example.](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=384)

The sample code there reads something like this:

```
public class DirListOnly { 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
    String dirname = "/java"; 
    File f1 = new File(dirname); 
    FilenameFilter only = new OnlyExt("html"); 
    String s[] = f1.list(only); 
  for (int i=0; i < s.length; i++) { 
    System.out.println(s[i]); 
  } 
 } 
}
```

where `OnlyExt` is the class as defined below.

```
public class OnlyExt implements FilenameFilter { 
    String ext; 
public OnlyExt(String ext) { 
    this.ext = "." + ext; 
  } 
public boolean accept(File dir, String name) { 
    return name.endsWith(ext); 
  } 
}
```

Now you can enter any desired filters such as .mp3 or .pdf or any of your choice.

Comment: But what kind of factors should be checked in accept()? Is there a law    or something? Or do I have to think it out by myself?